# how to auto fill an IntegerField in django model based on a M2M relation?

Tags: python, django, orm, m2m

I have a model named Post, and this model has a many to many relation with another model named LikeIps.

```
class Post(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
     summary = models.TextField()
     content = RichTextField()
     likes = models.ManyToManyField(LikeIP, related_name="liked_posts", blank=True)
     like_count = models.IntegerField(editable=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

I want to fill `likes_count` field automatically base on the number of object in `likes` query set something like this:

```
like_count = obj.likes.count()
```

how should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You  can use Django signals docs here [Django Post-save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save)
This will be called after the object is stored inside db, so you can make changes in the instance.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Post)
def save_post(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # or some other checks/logic
    if created:
        instance.like_count = obj.likes.count()
        instance.save()
```

Update: m2m field in a django model is updated after the record is saved in db. So post_save signal could be used.